# Identity in ASP.NET Core 6 micro services

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, rabbitmq, .net-6.0, rpc

I have services, one of which is used for authorization and authentication (Identity Service - localhost:7096) which uses identity system configuration, the other for sharing resources with authenticating users (Application Service -localhost:7141).

The problem starts when I try to fetch the name of an already logged in user from Identity Services to Application Service using RPC model RabbitMq.

So first what I do is to use the endpoint which is in IdentityServices  to fetch the name of the already logged in user

```
private async void ConsumerReceived(object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs e)
{
        var response = "";

        var body = e.Body.ToArray();
        var props = e.BasicProperties;
        var replyProps = _channel.CreateBasicProperties();
        replyProps.CorrelationId = props.CorrelationId;

        try
        {
            var wee = _serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();

            var client = wee.CreateClient();

            var loggedUserName = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:7096/get-logged-in-user-name");

            response = await loggedUserName.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(E);
            response = "null";
        }
        finally
        {
            var responseBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);
            _channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                routingKey: props.ReplyTo,
                basicProperties: replyProps,
                body: responseBytes);

            _channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: e.DeliveryTag,
                multiple: false);
        }
}
```

This method is used by the controller with endpoint **get-logged-in-user-name** to return the name

```
public static class ClaimPrincipleExtension
{
    public static string GetUsername(this ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        return user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
    }
}
```

And strangely, I noticed that when I activate the endpoint in Application Service to send a request to the rpc server (which is located in IdentityService) it tries to return a string of the logged-in user's name to pass it to application service, but in the above projects I get the same the error shown below, but when I type the raw string in the controller to return, everything works fine.
GetUsername - works when I call it directly in IdentityService, but when I try to call it using Application Service it doesn't work

```
[HttpGet("get-logged-in-user-name")]
public string GetLoggedInUserName()
{
        string username = User.GetUsername(); //!< -get current logged in userName
        return username; //!< -this invoke error in rpc Server and Client .
        // return "ExampleUser"; //! <- with this all work fine
}
```

Error:

> at Shared.Abstraction.Extensions.ClaimPrincipleExtension.GetUsername(ClaimsPrincipal user) in /Users/michal/Desktop/MyDateApp/Shared/Extensions/ClaimPrincipleExtension.cs:line 10
> at IdentityServer.Application.Controllers.UserController.GetLoggedInUserName() in /Users/michal/Desktop/MyDateApp/MicroServices/IdentityServer/IdentityServer.Application/Controllers/UserController.cs:line 41
> at lambda_method3(Closure , Object , Object[] )
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

## HEADERS

Host: localhost:7096`

Comment: if someone have convection how i can do it to work, please answer to the question !

Comment: You only show a stack trace, no exception message. Also, if all your services call each other all the time, they aren't really "micro", just decoupled.

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't see any other exceptions message other than the one I posted

Comment: @CodeCaster these services do not talk to each other all the time, only when I need to create a userProfile and for that I need to provide a username from the other service

Comment: No, that is not an error message, that is just the stack trace. The actual error message is missing.